# Set selected value of dropdown menu in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I have an ASP.Net MVC view which inherits from a ViewModel. The ViewModel contains data from two entities in the model:

```
public PaginatedList<Entry> Entries { get; private set; }
public SelectList ColumnValues { get; private set; }
```

These two properties are used on the view, which is based on a list template.
The list iterates through the Entries list and displays a table row for each of them. Within one of the table cells in the row is a DropDownList populated from the **ColumnValues** propery from the ViewModel.

I can get the DropDownList to set it's selected item using the following:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ColumnValue", Model.ColumnValues)
```

This renders the page, each row with a DropDownList in one of the cells. However the selected value is always set to the 'ColumnValue' for the first row, and is like this for all of the rows.

How would I go about modifying my code so that the selected value of the DropDownList matches the  ColumnValue for each inividual entry.

The aim is to produce a kind of editable datagrid with links to post back the changes per row using AJAX.

Comment: To summarize. I'm trying to replicate a datagrid, using a for each loop in the view. I have seen people mention doing this but no one has posted an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using DropDownListFor() in the View and setting the **selectList** to the following works:

```
new SelectList(Model.ColumnValues,"ColumnValue","ColumnValue", item.associatedField)
```

This doesn't seem to be a great way of doing things, but it works. And that's the most important thing right now. Any further comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that `ViewData["ColumnValue"] = "5"`. Now in your `ColumnValues` select list you need to have an item with the value = "5" and it will automatically be selected. For example:

```
ColumnValues = new SelectList(new[] {
    new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Item 1" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Item 2" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Item 3" }
}, "Value", "Text");
```

and then `ViewData["ColumnValue"] = "2"` will automatically preselect the second item.

Comment: I'm not using the ViewData[""] method. I'm using a ViewModel, so I have Model.Entries and Model.ColumnValues. Then looping through the Model.Entries enumerable which is a PaginatedList<T> (inherits from List<T>). The problem is that I need the selected item in the view to be different for each iteration of the for each loop. So it reflects the value in that row of data.

Comment: @Banford, if you are using a view model why aren't you using a strongly typed helper: `Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ColumnValue, Model.ColumnValues)`? Then all you have to do in your controller is set the `model.ColumnValue` to some value that is present in the `ColumnValues` collection.

Comment: Switching to DropDownListFor worked for populating the boxes but still didn't select the value. I couldn't see a way of setting this in the controller. So I've had to construct the SelectList in the view, setting the selected value at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You might create a custom html helper as indicated in my updated code (Updated Code - for MyDropdownListFor) on [Set Class Attribute for certain records of Dropdownlist in MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765439/set-class-attribute-for-certain-records-of-dropdownlist-in-mvc4) and use "Selected" attribute as Class attribute.
Hope this helps.