# Set Class Attribute for certain records of Dropdownlist in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, attributes, html-helper, html-select

I populate Dropdownlist from database and I want to show certain elements in red by setting their "class" attribute. So, I tried lots of ways and later I have created a custom HTML Helper for Dropdownlist. But it does not make any sense and although it seems to be added class attribute, this paramater cannot pass to Razor View from Controller. Could you help pls?

**MyHelper.cs:**

```
public static MvcHtmlString Custom_DropdownList(this HtmlHelper helper, string name,  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list, object htmlAttributes)
{        
    TagBuilder dropdown = new TagBuilder("select");
    dropdown.Attributes.Add("name", name);
    dropdown.Attributes.Add("id", name);
    StringBuilder options = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {            
        options = options.Append("<option value='" + item.Value + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>");
    }
    dropdown.InnerHtml = options.ToString();
    dropdown.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(dropdown.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

**Controller:**

```
private void PopulateMeetingsDropDownList(object selectedMeetings = null)
{
    var meetingsQuery = repository.Meetings
    .Join(repository.Cities, m => m.MeetingCityId, c => c.CityID,
    (m, c) => new
    {
        CityID = c.CityID,
        CityName = c.CityName,
        MeetingDate = m.MeetingStartDate
    }
    )
    .OrderBy(x => x.CityID)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(
    i => new
    {
        CityID = i.CityID,
        Name = string.Format(
        "{0} ({1:dd MMMM yyyy})",
        i.CityName, i.MeetingDate),
        Expired = i.MeetingDate < DateTime.UtcNow
    }
    ).ToList();

    var selectItems = new List<SelectListItem>(meetingsQuery.Count);
    foreach (var record in meetingsQuery)
    {
        var item = new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = record.Name,
            Value = record.Name
        };
        if (record.Expired)
        {
            item.Attributes.Add("class", "disabled"); //!!! Problem on this line
        }
            selectItems.Add(item);
    }
    ViewData["MeetingId"] = new SelectList(meetingsQuery, "CityID", "Name", selectedMeetings);
}
```

But after applying this method I got an error "'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a definition for 'Attributes' and no extension method 'Attributes' accepting a first argument of type...". So, I think I need to use another property or helper to assign class properties to custom racords (there is no problem filtering records on the *"if (record.Expired)"* line).

**View:**

```
@Html.Custom_DropdownList("MeetingId", ViewData["MeetingId"] as SelectList, new { id = "meetingId"})
```

Could you clarify me how to provide this? Thanks in advance.

---

*Here is the modificated code for having ability for both Class and Disabled attributes:*

**Updated Code (for MyDropdownListFor):**

**Custom HTML Helper Class:**

```
public static class MyHelpers
{
    public class MySelectItem : SelectListItem
    {
        public string Class { get; set; } 
        public string Disabled { get; set; }
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString MyDropdownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<MySelectItem> list, string optionLabel, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return MyDropdownList(htmlHelper, ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression), list, optionLabel, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString MyDropdownList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, IEnumerable<MySelectItem> list, string optionLabel, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        TagBuilder dropdown = new TagBuilder("select");
        dropdown.Attributes.Add("name", name);
        dropdown.Attributes.Add("id", name);
        StringBuilder options = new StringBuilder();

        // Make optionLabel the first item that gets rendered.
        if (optionLabel != null)
            options = options.Append("<option value='" + String.Empty + "'>" + optionLabel + "</option>");

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            if(item.Disabled == "disabled")
                options = options.Append("<option value='" + item.Value + "' class='" + item.Class + "' disabled='" + item.Disabled + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>");
            else
                options = options.Append("<option value='" + item.Value + "' class='" + item.Class + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>");
        }
        dropdown.InnerHtml = options.ToString();
        dropdown.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(dropdown.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    private void PopulateMeetingsDropDownList(object selectedMeetings = null)
    {
        var meetingsQuery = repository.Meetings
            .Join(repository.Cities, m => m.MeetingCityId, c => c.CityID,
                (m, c) => new
                {
                    CityID = c.CityID,
                    CityName = c.CityName,
                    MeetingDate = m.MeetingStartDate
                }
            )
            .OrderBy(x => x.CityID)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(
                i => new
                {
                    Value = i.CityID.ToString(),
                    DisplayValue = string.Format(
                        "{0} ({1:dd MMMM yyyy})",
                        i.CityName, i.MeetingDate),
                    Expired = i.MeetingDate < DateTime.UtcNow
                }
            ).ToList();


        var selectItems = new List<MyHelpers.MySelectItem>(meetingsQuery.Count);
        foreach (var record in meetingsQuery)
        {
            var item = new MyHelpers.MySelectItem
            {
                Text = record.DisplayValue,
                Value = record.Value
            };
            if (record.Expired)
            {
                item.Class = "disabled";
                item.Disabled = "disabled";
            }
            selectItems.Add(item);
        }
        ViewBag.MeetingData = selectItems;
    }
```

**View:**

```
<label>Meeting</label>           
@Html.MyDropdownListFor(m => m.MeetingId, ViewBag.MeetingData as    List<MyHelpers.MySelectItem>, "---- Select ----", 
new { name = "meetingId", id = "meetingId"})
```

Comment: Check out this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/7537628/674700](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7537628/674700).

Comment: It is a static list and I think that topic is not so related to my question.

Comment: the easiest way is to concatenate text property with text and class something like text#class and then in helper split it ... from the code perspective it is not right .. but this thing won't change your existing code.... if on future you want to add more attributes or fun then Slavo 's answer is right... create custom one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR;** You are using `SelectList`, but you don't need to.

Create a new view model class, which you will pass to the view. It will contain all the properties you need, and may look like this:

**Custom class to hold info about items:**

```
public class CustomSelectItem
{
    public string Text {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
    public string Class {get;set;}
    public bool Selected {get;set;}
}
```

Since you are passing this data using ViewData, you don't have a limitation and you can put anything there. I advise that you use ViewBag instead of ViewData.

In your controller you can create a new `List<CustomSelectItem>` and pass it. When building the collection, if the item is expired just set the Class property to "disabled" or whatever you are using. Here is the code (I skipped the part where you get the meetings):

**Controller:**

```
var selectItems = new List<CustomSelectItem>(meetingsQuery.Count);
foreach (var record in meetingsQuery)
{
    var item = new CustomSelectItem
    {
        Text = record.Name,
        Value = record.Name
    };
    if (record.Expired)
    {
        item.Class = "disabled";
    }
    selectItems.Add(item);
}
ViewBag.MeetingData = selectItems;
```

Then modify the custom helper method you have created to  accept a collection of `CustomSelectItem` instead of `SelectListItem`. You can write directly the HTML, because you have access to the Class property.

**Custom helper method:**

```
public static MvcHtmlString Custom_DropdownList(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, IList<CustomSelectItem> list, object htmlAttributes)
{
    TagBuilder dropdown = new TagBuilder("select");
    dropdown.Attributes.Add("name", name);
    dropdown.Attributes.Add("id", name);
    StringBuilder options = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        options = options.Append("<option value='" + item.Value + "' class='" + item.Class + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>");
    }
    dropdown.InnerHtml = options.ToString();
    dropdown.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(dropdown.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

Once this is done, you can invoke the helper from the view as follows:

**View:**

```
@Html.Custom_DropdownList("MeetingId", ViewBag.MeetingData as List<CustomListItem>, new { id = "meetingId"})
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But if it is possible could you edit your reply containing the other changes on View and Controller (if need also Custom HTML helper). BR.

Comment: I also tried to apply this logic. But I encountered "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type" error. So, could you give me the usage of the DDL on View and the Helper method in the new class? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I have just found opportunity in order to apply your code. As you might see the last updated code above, I also added "Disabled" attribute to your approach. On the other hand, I have noticed that your approach cannot be used **Html.DropDownListFor** or I cannot. >>>

Comment: >>>Many thanks for your help and nice approach, but if you update my **last** updated code so that it can be used with **Html.DropDownListFor** like on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536631/adding-html-class-tag-under-option-in-html-dropdownlist/7537628#7537628 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416498/custom-attributes-for-selectlistitem-in-mvc page, I will select you reply as answer for this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can inherit the SelectList and add your own properties to the class, like this:

```
public class MySelectListItem : SelectListItem
{
    public bool Highlighted { get; set; }
}
```

Once you have the custom class, you write your helper based on it. You can apply different css classes or change the style attribute.

```
public static class MyHtmlHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListHighlighted(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, IEnumerable<MySelectListItem> itens)
    {
        StringBuilder dropDown = new St();
        dropDown.AppendFormat("<select id='{0}' name='{0}'>", name);

        foreach (var item in itens)
        {
            dropDown.AppendFormat("<option selected='{2}' value='{1}' class='{3}'>{0}</option>",
                item.Text,
                item.Value,
                item.Selected ? "selected" : "",
                item.Highlighted ? "highlighted" : "normal");
        }

        dropDown.Append("</select>");

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(dropDown.ToString());
    }
}
```

In your view (don't forget to add the namespace of your HTML helper class at the web.config or at the view):

```
@Html.DropDownListHighlighted("DropDown", ViewData["DropDownOptions"] as List<MySelectListItem>)
```

**DropDownListHighlightedFor**

You could do something like this to implementation a simple DropDownListHighlightedFor:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListHighlightedFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<MySelectListItem> itens)
{
    return DropDownListHighlighted(htmlHelper, ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression), itens);
}
```

In the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListHighlightedFor(x => x.Option, ViewData["DropDownOptions"] as List<MySelectListItem>)
```

Comment: Trying to apply this logic I encountered first "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type" and then "Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class" errors. After looking for the error I have applied all the suggestion on forums, but when I use static keyword I get another errors. So, could you please look at the code above and give an example indicating the HTML Helper and View code of DropDownListHighlighted usage line like @Html.DropDownListHighlighted("meetingId", ViewData["MeetingId"] as MySelectListItem).

Comment: I added at the answer the view code. Note that the helper is expecting a IEnumerable.

Comment: About your second error, your extension methods must be defined inside a static class (more details: [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually I have tried your method first before Slavo's, but although it is very similar the other one unfortunately it did not work. I have tried to correct the errors, but nothing has changed. Neverthless I voted up your response as your approach is also very useful. Thank you very much. On the other hand, I have not decided the full answer yet due to no ability **Html.DropDownListFor** with the other answer. >>>

Comment: >>> So, if you update my last code so that it can be used **DropDownlistFor** extension method like on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536631/adding-html-class-tag-under-option-in-html-dropdownlist/7537628#7537628 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416498/custom-attributes-for-selectlistitem-in-mvc page, I will select your answer as answer. Thanks in advance...

Comment: I added it to my answer.

Comment: @ Alexandre Junges : Thank you very much for your help. I have managed to use custom helper with DropdownListFor method and extra optionLabel property ("Select"). I updated my code above so that people needing such a kind of example can use easily. BR.